# LINQ query to Observable collection

Tags: c#, linq, datagrid, observablecollection

I've got an observable collection that contains multiple DocumentEntry objects that each have a language property. I present this in a DataGrid so that the documents can be updated, but that became too many entries, so I've added a combobox with language names and now I need to present only the documents of that language.

The collection of documents is an ObservableCollection, but when I say

```
myDataGrid.DataContext = (from d in documents where d.language == selectedLanguage select d);
```

the result of the LINQ query is not an observable collection. Do I filter this the right way at all? How can I best filter an ObservableCollection in my datagrid, in this case by language?

Cheers

Nik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to yous [CollectionViewSource.Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.filter.aspx)

Something like this

```
myDataGrid.DataContext = documents;
CollectionViewSource cvs = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(documents);
vse.Filter = delegate(object obj)
{
   Document doc = obj as Document;
   if(doc == null)
       return false;
   return doc.language == selectedLanguage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

XAML:

```
<Listbox x:name="MyLB"/>
```

CB:

```
Dim q = from c as myobject in myobservablecollection where c.CriteriaA= CriteriaB

MyLb.Itemsource =  q.ToList
```

Fundamental being : Datacontext can only be set for objects which have been created. As far as LINQ is concerned, You need to pass the LINQ result query as TOLIST to reflect the filtered view .

NOTE: This will not update as ToList is a generic list and has no INotifyPropertyChanged implemented.